# Use Java library with Xcode, Objective C, and Cocoa

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, xcode3.2

I would like to use an open source library that's written in Java to create a Cocoa desktop application.

Ideally, I would use the Java library as the model, and write my own Objective C controller classes and Cocoa views.  Is this possible in Xcode?  What options do I have (if any)?

Or, would you recommend rewriting the parts of the Java library I need into Objective C (or C)?

Fyi, I have zero Java experience and I'm fairly new to programming (under 2 years experience).  The languages I currently study and use are Ruby and Objective C (and the Cocoa framework).

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Comment: There is no easy way to bridge Objective-C and Java (you can use JNI, but that's far from easy). Perhaps you can tell us what Java library you want to use. There may be a C/C++/Objective-C alternative.

Comment: Try a combination of MacRuby and JRuby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently joined the Cocoa developers mailing list.  Someone basically asked this exact question and the consensus was to use JNI.  However, MacRuby and JRuby is an interesting thought.  Therefore, I suppose the real answer is it's possible but not easy.